# How to do a reverse-proxy with Nginx for multiple instance of Meteor

Tags: meteor, nginx, reverse-proxy, meteor-up

**Problem**

I'm trying to deploy multiple instance of [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) on one single server web.

Every project have his own domain name (say 'A' -> 'A.com', 'B' ..), but server have a single web port:80. So I want to use [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/) to [**follow this article**](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/wiki/Using-Meteor-Up-with-NginX-vhosts)

**Deployment**

I'm using [meteor-up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) (version [mupx](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx)) to deploy each app. This is the cropped example of `mup.json`

```
{
  "appName": "A",
  "env": {
    "PORT": "3001",
    "ROOT_URL": "http://www.A.com"
  },
}
```

**Nginx**

This is my version of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/A.com.conf`

```
server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           A.com;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/app.dev.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/app.dev.error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

**Result**

For every domain, when I call:

```
  :80   -> Ngninx Welcome page
  :3001 -> A.com
  :3002 -> B.com
 ..
```

How can I got the right site, based on domain name when I call the `whatever:80` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is simply to add all possible version of the server name instead of only the domain name.

Like so

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/A.com.conf`

```
server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           A A.com *.A.com;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/app.dev.access.log;
  [...]
```